# Syncing google task

Tags: google-calendar

I am knew in android family and recently purchased note 3 all the fuction and details a well operated but I cant sync task from google calender in my s planner . The other details from google calender sync very well but not the task.  Can any one pl help?

Answer (score 1):

Google does not provide a native client for syncing tasks. There are plenty of good apps on Google Play that will do this. [GTasks](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.dayup.gtask) is one good example.